# Default page based on condition in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller like this one:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/page")
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {

        if (condition) {
            return "default_page";
        }

        // some logic
        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "page2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page2() {

        if (condition) {
            return "default_page";
        }

        // some logic
        return "page2";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/page3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page3() {

        if (condition) {
            return "default_page";
        }

        // some logic
        return "page3";
    }
}
```

As you can see all the methods start with:

```
if (condition) {
    return "default_page";
}
```

Is there an easy way (without additional classes or aspects) to extract this code and indicate that it should be executed for all of the methods?

Comment: Have a look at `@ControllerAdvice` http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice

Comment: Aspects are made exactly for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do the thing you would like to do just with annotations. You need some logic before controller's method. And there is two options: use aspects and use interceptor. Interceptor in this case is more appropriate. The benefits of this approach, that other methods of controller know nothing about `condition`, and remain simple and clean. If you'll decide to change or remove condition, you don't need to change anything in other methods.

Add default method in controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/page")
public class PageController {
    ....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/defaultPage")
    public String defaultPage() {
        return "default_page";
    }    
}
```

Create new interceptor class:

```
public class PageInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
             HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {    

        if(condition){
            httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/page/default_page")
                .forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);    
        }   
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, 
            Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, 
            Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {}
}
```

Register interceptor in application configuration. If you use xml-file config, add:

```
<bean id="pageInterceptor" class="PageInterceptor"/>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/page" />
        <ref bean="pageInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Or if you use Java-based config:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public PageInterceptor pageInterceptor(){
        return new PageInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MappedInterceptor(new String[]{"/page"}, pageInterceptor()));
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }
}
```

Note, that there is a mapping to `/page` url, for make interceptor work only for `PageController`. Additionally, you can register and use this interceptor for other controllers, after little code changes.